# Write Cross Apply to select last row with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make request for SQL Table which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentMark (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    StudentId int NOT NULL,
    Mark int
);
```

Is that possible to select StudentMark rows where row should be last row for each user with mark greater than 4.

I'm trying to accomplish that by doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].StudentMark outer
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM [dbo].StudentMark inner
    WHERE inner.StudentId= outer.StudentId AND inner.Mark>4
) cApply
```

But that doesn't do what's needed. Could anyone help?

Comment: *"But that doen't do what's needed. "* Where's your `ORDER BY` if you have a `TOP`?

Comment: How do you define "last row"?  Usually such a query would use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Last without date field; I'm no expert enough. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, "last row" is based on `id`.  If so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].StudentMark sm CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) sm2.*
      FROM [dbo].StudentMark sm2
      WHERE sm2.StudentId = sm.StudentId AND sm2.Mark > 4
      ORDER BY sm2.id DESC
     ) sm2;
```

EDIT:

If you only want the last row per student with `Mark > 4`, then use filtering:

```
select sm.*
from dbo.StudentMark sm
where sm.id = (select max(sm2.id)
               from dbo.StudentMark sm2
               where sm2.studentId = sm.studentId and sm2.Mark > 4
              );
```

Comment: It doesn't do the trick. it just returns for each equal id from outer list all values from inner. But i wanna get like grouping  for each id

Comment: @twirkhacked sample data and expected results would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I am curious if something like this will actually get what you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT  Data.StudentId,
        Data.Id,
        Data.Mark
FROM
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentMark.StudentId ORDER BY StudentMark.Id DESC) AS RowNumber,
            StudentMark.StudentId,
            StudentMark.Id,
            StudentMark.Mark
    FROM    dbo.StudentMark
) AS Data
WHERE   Data.RowNumber = 1
```

What this will do is get the row number of each and then let you filter by the row number on what is returned. I changed it to look for the first row instead of the last row, but sorted DESC, such that you will get what effectively would have been the last row entered for a student id.

Comment: Note that as the question was a little vague at the intent, this may not be the exact solution, but possibly show a new route that can be taken.

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT *
FROM StudentMark A
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 Mark
 FROM StudentMark B
 WHERE A.StudentId = B.StudentId
 ORDER BY StudentId
)M
WHERE M.Mark > 4
```